# Limit of $\ln(1\cdot\ln(2\cdot\ln(3\cdot\ln(4\cdots))))$

Tags: analysis, limits

I recently asked for the limit

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \ln(1+\ln(2+\ln(3+\ln(4+\cdots+\ln(n))\ldots)$$.

But what about the similar limit

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \ln(1\cdot \ln(2\cdot \ln(3\cdot \ln(4\cdots \ln(n))\ldots)$$ ?

This limit also seems to exist

```
? n=10^5;x=log(n);while(n>1,x=log(x*(n-1));n=n-1);print(x)
0.3132776395465558314822583305
```

For n=100 the same value appears within this precision.

Is there a proof of convergence also for this limit ?

Can the limit be expressed by a closed form ?

Comment: Please, please, do not use $*$ for multiplication. In mathematics, $*$ is for *convolution*. (I fixed it for you.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: You over-fixed it. You changed the * in the code too.

Comment: @user3533 Ah, so I did. Global search/replace in emacs, argh. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @Neal: $\ln(2\ln(3\ln(4)))=\ln2+\ln\ln(3\ln4)=\ln2+\ln(\ln(3)+\ln\ln(4))=\cdot$?

Comment: @Peter It is very easy to get that result, of course. Until you take a second look and realize it is wrong. I am surprised, however, at the upvotes on that comment. Why did it take so long before someone realized? Maybe we should all slow down once in a while.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen What comment? *innocent whistle* (But seriously: Thanks :) )

Comment: @Neal Don't know, guess I was just commenting on the weather. (But seriously: You're welcome.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a closed form, but there is a way to make this limit look even more interesting:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(1\cdot \ln(2\cdot \ln(3\cdot \ln(4\cdots (\ln n) ))))=$$

$$
=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln\ln\ln(3^2\cdot \ln^2(4\cdots(\ln n)))=
$$

$$
=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln\ln\ln\ln^2(4^{3} \ln^3(5\cdots(\ln n) ))=
$$

$$
=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln \ln \ln \ln^2 \dots \ln^{n-2} n^{n-1}=x
$$

Then, assuming that the limit $x$ exists, we can exponentiate $2$ times and get:

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln \ln^2 \ln^3 \dots \ln^{n-2} n^{n-1}=e^{e^x}
$$

Considering, that $n >> 1$, we can further simplify the expression:

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln \ln^2 \ln^3 \dots \ln^{n} n^{n}=e^{e^x}
$$

It's not immediately apparent that we are allowed to make this last simplification, but for some reason it appears to work numerically.

Comment: $\ln\ln 2+\ln\ln\ln 3+\ln\ln\ln\ln 4+\dots$ is incorrect

Comment: @GEdgar, yeah, I see it now. Thanks

Comment: Still wrong. $ 2\cdot\log(x) = \log(x^2)$ where you square all of $x$, not just the first factor.

Comment: @GEdgar, how about now?

Comment: Now looks right.